# To access property of object nested in array using destructuring

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

How to access property of object nested in array using destructuring? Following is my code:

```
 var weatherObj = {
      weather: [{
        id: 721,
        main: "Haze",
        description: "haze",
        icon: "50d"
      }]
    };
```

For example i want to decalre variable description with value "haze".

Answer (score 2):

**Decomposing all levels**

You can decompose one level at a time. First, get the `weather` property of weatherObj. Next, access the first element of the array in that property. Finally, you decompose the desired property from the element:

```
var {weather} = weatherObj
var [w1] = weather;
var {description} = w1;
```

**Particular property with nesting**

If you are only interested in the `description` property, you can nest patterns as follows:

```
var {weather: [{description}]} = weatherObj;
// description === 'haze'
```

You can also assign the value to a variable with a different name than the property that you decompose just like you do it with the basic decomposition:

```
var {weather: [{description: desc}]} = weatherObj;
// desc === 'haze'
```

Comment: Was wondering how to rename properties when destructuring (and not importing). Learned something new today, thanks!